# Compiling .json file with xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-api

I'm trying to implement the Google Calendar API to a Xamarin application. Using google's guide online, I've got the code to work as a console app. This works with "crendentials.json" file which will be modified after the first run of the application. This normally does not cause any issues. However, when compiled to Xamarin.android and run via USB-debugging, I get an I/O exception, because of the JSON-file missing from directory. I need the file to be able to be read and written to.

I've gotten the application to read the JSON-file, however, this is achieved by loading the file as an embedded resource, which causes the file to be read-only and the app throws an I/O exception.

```
        // Current code from application
        string jsonFileName = "credentials.json";
        var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");

        using (stream)
        {
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }
```

I/O exception from credential = `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...)` caused by the file (stream) being read-only.

Comment: at startup, you need to copy the file to a user-writable folder

Comment: Copy it out of the assembly (or app bundle) and place it within the app's sandbox (cache, file, ... ) so it can be modified. FYI: Not sure it will work even then as the `Google.Apis.Calendar.v3` is not supported on mobile, I know the included OAuth will not work, but you can work around that by using your own. They do support Android/iOS via native wrappers using GoogleSignIn and the REST APIs

Comment: Okay thanks. I did anticipate some issues with authentication, however, just getting to that part has been a small roadblock. I'm completly new to xamarin and mobile development, so I think I got some things to learn!